# How to Create a Custom Container in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, containers

I am not sure if I have this right ... but can anyone point me to a resource that shows how to create a custom container in ASP.NET (Specifically MVC). By container I am talking about a container that is globally available during a session like a DI container (i.e. Ninject or UNity). Thanks in advance.

Comment: May i know, for what purpose you are looking to create your own container ?

Comment: I am working on a multi tenancy application and thought I might try and use it to hold tenant specific information

Comment: A container is for resolving component dependencies. It's not going to persist data across requests. You need to store your data in the Session object for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i assume that you don't know some available resources to make it easier than create a new container:  you can use [Mvc Turbine](http://mvcturbine.codeplex.com/) which is already supports using any kind of container, in fact it implements a complete Web Application.

if you already know that:
well, i think that your question likes: how to make a car !
there is no specific way to make a container, and i tell you what!! it is a hard mission (not mission impossible) but it very long journey,i don't know if it worth to start from scratch, but if you insist, you can at least try to modify an existing one, like you said, UNITY, or Ninject.  however   I'm using [Windsor Castle](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html) Container with my Mvc application and it's great,
and as you said it is available to use during session